# Prevent duplicate objects but allow Update with Cloud-Code and Parse.com as backend

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I've an issue with Cloud Code.My problem is explained as:

1. I've a class "MyClass"
2. I want only one object saved in my backend referring to a particular property  ("myID")
3. If a user try to save this object and there is not any with the same "myID" save it
4. If a user try to save this object and THERE IS ALREADY ONE with the same "myID" update the field ("address") for the existing object.

I try to this using this code:

```
var MyObject = Parse.Object.extend("MyClass");
    Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("MyClass", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.object.get("myID")) {
        response.error('A MyObject must have a unique myID.');
    } else {
        var query = new Parse.Query(MyClass);
        query.equalTo("myID", request.object.get("myID"));
        query.first({
            success: function(object) {
                if (object) {
                    object.set('address',request.object.get("address"));
                    object.save().then(function () {
                        response.error('Updated existing MyObject address');
                    },function (error) {
                        response.error("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                    });
                } else {
                    response.success();
                }
            },
            error: function(error) {
                response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this MyObject object.");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

But this doesn't works and in my Parse.com Log says:

> Result: Error: 142 Error: 124 Too many recursive calls into Cloud Code

I know can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Cloud update unique column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34499751/parse-cloud-update-unique-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `beforeSave` method that is triggered when an object of `MyClass` should be stored. If this method detects that the object searched for already exists, it modifies this object and tries to store it. But this triggers again the `beforeSave` method, and so on, an infinite loop.

You could do it on the client side: Check, if the object exists. If not, create it, but if so, add an entry to it. But you should be aware that you will have a problem: If more than 1 client executes this code at the same time, they could all find out that the object does not exist yet, and more than 1 object will be created.

I would thus create such an object right from the beginning, and use the atomic operation `addUniqueObject:forKey:` to add entries to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the object in `beforeSave` - any changes you've made to `request.object` will be saved when you call `response.success()`