# Parse Cloud update unique column

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have used this code to save the data using Parse Cloud, I have a unique column "number_plate" I am facing a problem and that is when I try to update the object I'm unable to do so.

```
var Car = Parse.Object.extend("Car");

// Check if number plate is set, and enforce uniqueness based on the number plate column.
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Car", function(request, response) {
  if (!request.object.get("number_plate")) {
    response.error('The number plate was not provided.');
  } else {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Car);
    query.equalTo("number_plate", request.object.get("number_plate"));
    query.first({
      success: function(object) {
        if (object) {
          response.error("A Car with this number plate already exists.");
        } else {
          response.success();
        }
      },
      error: function(error) {
        response.error("Could not validate uniqueness for this Car because the number plate is repeated.");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

**

> UPDATE:  The new code I used according to the given answer:

**

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Car", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.object.isNew()) {
      // Let existing object updates go through
      response.success();
    }
    var query = new Parse.Query("Car");
    // Add query filters to check for uniqueness
    query.equalTo("number_plate", request.object.get("number_plate"));
    query.first().then(function(existingObject) {
      if (existingObject) {
        // Update existing object. here you can do all the object updates you want 
        if (request.object.get("car_model") != undefined){
          object.set("car_model",request.object.get("car_model"));
        }

        if (request.object.get("car_name") != undefined){
          object.set("car_name",request.object.get("car_name"));
        }
        if (request.object.get("year") != undefined){
          object.set("year",request.object.get("year"));
        }
        return existingObject.save();
        response.error();
      } else {
        // Pass a flag that this is not an existing object
        return Parse.Promise.as(false);
      }
    }).then(function(existingObject) {
      if (existingObject) {
        // Existing object, stop initial save
        response.error("Existing object");
      } else {
        // New object, let the save go through
        response.success();
      }
    }, function (error) {
      response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The key in this case is to work with the promises.

What you are trying to reach is something like the following:

```
Parse.Cloud.beforeSave("Car", function(request, response) {
    if (!request.object.isNew()) {
      // Let existing object updates go through
      response.success();
    }
    var query = new Parse.Query("Car");
    // Add query filters to check for uniqueness
    query.equalTo("number_plate", request.object.get("number_plate"));
    query.first().then(function(existingObject) {
      if (existingObject) {
        // Update existing object. here you can do all the object updates you want 
        if (request.object.get("columnToUpdate") != undefined){
          existingObject.set('columnToUpdate',request.object.get("columnToUpdate"));
        }
        return existingObject.save();
        response.error();
      } else {
        // Pass a flag that this is not an existing object
        return Parse.Promise.as(false);
      }
    }).then(function(existingObject) {
      if (existingObject) {
        // Existing object, stop initial save
        response.error("Existing object");
      } else {
        // New object, let the save go through
        response.success();
      }
    }, function (error) {
      response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks @adolfosrs sorry there was a problem in my connection, I tried your code now it accepts all values even if its a duplicate :\

Comment: what changes you made on the code I gave you? Did you try debbuging using `console.log(...)` to see whats happening inside the function?

Comment: I will post the changes I made in the question

Comment: The new objects are not accepted if they aren't unique, but the previous ones are updated without any problems even if the value isn't unique

Comment: so whats the problem? do you want to be able to update the values or not? Not sure if I understood what problem you are facing now. Could you explain a little better?

Comment: I don't want the user to update the values if the number_plate is not unique. like e.g. if the user decided to change the numberplate to something else and that value was already used by another user, I want to display an error, but the code is letting the non-unique numberplates go through

Comment: @amateurprogrammer there is a typo in your code. where you are using `object.set(...)` you must use `existingObject.set(...)`.

Comment: Changed it but the problem still didn't end